# Questions about God

Tags: discussion

> [Isn't the knowledge of the non-existence of "God" objective?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/59972/33787)

This question has attracted answers that would make it a good reference for a whole range of related (and not very good) questions. Should we reopen it?

Comment: Ignoring the answers, is the question as of current writing eligible to be reopened? The existence of (good) answers doesn't automatically make the question on-topic. Fix the question if possible, otherwise just leave it closed.

Comment: In general I find "let's apply reason to God" type questions unconstructive, so no. But I'm thinking a model discussion such as this could be expedient...

Answer (score 1):

I liked the question, perhaps because I did not agree with what it suggested was the case, but still it was specific enough that it gave me an opportunity for an answer based on references I found interesting. I see no point answering something if I cannot ground the answer on a reference that I find valuable and relevant.

So not only did I up-vote the question early on, but I voted to leave it open and later voted to re-open it when it appeared in those review queues.

These kind of questions keep coming back. By closing them we mainly keep users from continuing to answer them.

But I don't mind answering a similar, but new, question again. Perhaps I can make the answer even better.

Comment: You can still refer users to the closed question. It doesn't get removed. That's not a reason to re-open it.

Comment: @Eliran The OP may feel obliged to delete, or worse, be discouraged to post better questions. The question could have been closed before Frank's answer (which I found illuminating), having a model thread for questionable questions, not only provide reference but also help the community better deal with them.

Comment: @Eliran I clarified the answer to remove the part about hiding the question. I don't really mind that the question is closed or left open. However, I don't think it serves any purpose to close it especially since it has drawn over 2000 views. Perhaps others will become more active on this site as a result.

Comment: @FrankHubeny I don't have a strong opinion about this particular question, but I don't think popularity is a reason not to close a question. In fact, if a popular question is unsuitable for this site then it might attract the wrong kind of activity, so we have all the more reason to close it.

Comment: @Eliran As I see it the question was suitable. People with high reputation who answer the question provide examples for others with less reputation.